# How do I create this type of shadow effect on the letters in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, effects, drop-shadow

How do I create this type of text effect in Illustrator?

[image: How do I create this type of text effect in Illustrator?]

I initially was doing it a little backwards where I created a copy behind my main text, nudged it down and to the right. Then created another copy of my main text with a stroke, outlined the stroke then essentially eliminated that from the second text copy creating a shadow effect. Then I grouped all my shadows and placed them above my main text however I still need to clean up some of them as they didn't quite line up with the shapes of the letters.

Can someone help provide a tutorial or instructions on how to get this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick tut. 
Create background with darker color then desired font. I used black. The write with chosen font what you want. 
[image: step1]

Add stroke, I've chosen 4pt. 
[image: step2]

Copy text, paste in place (shift+ctrl"cmd"+v). Remove stroke and change color to "shadowy" (20K in my case). 
[image: step3]

Paste text again. remove stroke, change to white and move it up and left "a notch". 
You should have something like this. 
[image: step4]

This way of doing this will give you more freedom to change the font later on. Just select all text boxes and switch to different one. And if you write the first text and then use "make envelope" (like in the case provided) and THEN make all the steps then all text boxes will behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal dropshadow, made by (most probably) copied text with darkened color that got slightly moved down and right (and placed under the initial letters) and then another text that got enlarged and it all got it's dark blue outline. That's how I would go for such an effect. Hope that helps ; )

Comment: it could also possibly be a offset inside cut by itself

Comment: Yup, there's many, many ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Like most things in Illustrator (and graphic arts in general) there are several different ways to achieve this effect.

If you want it to be fast you could, create a drop shadow with a 100% hardness on the edge and negative y-axis offset.

If you want more control over the text, create a duplicate text layer, change the fill color, warp/transform to get the look you want.

There are other ways, of course, "offset path" comes to mind.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I made a quick text effect in Illustrator, maybe it'll be helpful:
[download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ye6gmq1xrmt4ljh/text%20effect.ai?dl=0)

P.S.: I applied the effect to Arial Black font but it's fully editable and works on most of the fonts. I recommend using a bolder font however.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to just link a random place on internet here.  Instead write how on this page.

Comment: Hi huni, welcome to GDSE. Could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that your solution should be different than the accepted answer to be useful